# Why dont the axis tick marks get removed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have recently started getting into d3 and graph plotting.

Now I have constructed a very simple graph that should get animated with new data. The animation works however if I animate the axis change all tick marks stay inside the svg. Their opacity drops to something very low but never reaches 0. After a long running time my svg contains every tick mark ever created.

I have seperated my code in a plunker (see below code)

```
////////////////////////// LINE ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function createLine() {
  var random = d3.random.normal(0, 20),
    data = d3.range(22).map(random),
    svg = d3.select('#line').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 1000)
      .attr('height', 500);

  var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range([0, 800]);

  var axisX = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleX).orient('bottom')
    .ticks(5);

  var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-40, 40])
    .range([0, 400])
    .nice();

  var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleY).orient('right')
    .ticks(5);

  var increment = 0;

  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('basis')
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return scaleX(i + increment);
    })
    .y(function(d, i) {
      return scaleY(d);
    });

  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return scaleX(i + increment);
    })
    .y0(400)
    .y1(function(d, i) {
      return scaleY(d);
    });


  svg.append('defs').append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clip')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', 800)
    .attr('height', 400);

  var path = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(10, 50)')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append('path').datum(data).attr('d', line);

  var xAxis = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis-x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(10,250)').call(axisX);
  var yAxis = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'axis-y')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(820,50)').call(axisY);

  function tick() {
    data.push(random());

    path.attr('d', line)
      .attr('transform', null)
      .transition().duration(500).ease('linear')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + scaleX(increment - 1) + ')')
      .each('end', tick);

    ++increment;
    scaleX.domain([increment, increment + 20]);

    xAxis.transition().duration(500).ease('linear')
      .call(axisX);


    data.shift();
  }

  tick();
}
////////////////////////// LINE ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

http://plnkr.co/k4B1OxFBPwD3z9ARVrjg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The end event is invoked during the last asynchronous callback (tick)
>   after the transition duration and delay expires, after all tweens are
>   invoked with t=1. **Note that if the transition is superseded by a
>   later-scheduled transition on a given element, no end event will be
>   dispatched for that element; interrupted transitions do not trigger
>   end events.** For example, transition.remove schedules each element to
>   be removed when the transition ends, but if the transition is
>   interrupted, the element will not be removed.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix it: http://plnkr.co/KgdBVTmac1QLAxjgACDD

I ended up looking at the code used to generate the final example in [Mike Bostock's 'Path Transitions' tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/). The only difference I could see between that and your code was that the axis update\transition was happening *before* the path transition in Mike's.

So I reordered your code in `function tick()` to put:

```
path.attr('d', line)
    .attr('transform', null)
    .transition().duration(500).ease('linear')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + scaleX(increment - 1) + ')')
    .each('end', tick);
```

at the end of the function block, after:

```
xAxis.transition().duration(1000).ease('linear')
    .call(axisX);
```

and it seems to work fine. Instead of 'old' x-axis ticks hanging around in the DOM with `opacity: 0.000001`, they are removed. Frustratingly, I can't understand why this works at the moment!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. In the course of the day i came to the same conclusion and i don't know why this happens.

Comment: Your link to "This seems to fix it" is broken.